# Is it possible to CAST as FLOAT from an IIF statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to CAST as FLOAT from an IIF statement?

```
SELECT TOP 100 PeopleID, RateCount, IIF (People.RateCount < 100, 
CAST(People.RateCount/100 as FLOAT), 1) as RateWeight
FROM People WHERE People.RateCount > 0 ORDER BY People.DateAdded DESC
```

The result I'm getting is

```
PeopleID    RateCount   RateWeight
8548    674 1
135698  30  0
426755  2   0
336714  106 1
276739  43  0
536577  7   0
57674   81  0
79670   32  0
44674   901 1
146784  16  0
```

What I want is

```
PeopleID    RateCount   RateWeight
8548    674 1
135698  30  .30
426755  2   .02
336714  106 1
276739  43  .43
536577  7   .07
57674   81  .81
79670   32  .32
44674   901 1
146784  16  .16
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing division, the data types of the numbers being divided control the resulting data type. To get a FLOAT or DECIMAL result, one of the numbers must already be FLOAT or DECIMAL, i.e.:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PeopleID, 
    RateCount, 
    IIF (People.RateCount < 100, People.RateCount/CAST(100 as FLOAT), 1) as RateWeight
FROM People 
WHERE People.RateCount > 0 
ORDER BY People.DateAdded DESC
```

Alternately, get rid of the CAST and just make the value 100 into 100.0

```
SELECT TOP 100 PeopleID, 
    RateCount, 
    IIF (People.RateCount < 100, People.RateCount/100.0, 1) as RateWeight
FROM People 
WHERE People.RateCount > 0 
ORDER BY People.DateAdded DESC
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: For consistency I'd make all of the literal values `decimal`: `IIF( People.RateCount < 100.0, People.RateCount / 100.0, 1.0 )`.